# How to check that one word appears after other in cypress?

Tags: cypress

In cypress I have

**Book**
:This is the book of
**English**

how to test that 'Book:This is book of English' is in order ?
I not having single row I have multiple rows like this

`cy.get('span').then((Val)=>{ const text=val.text().trim(':').toString(); });`

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @AsadMusharaf needs an extra step:

```js
cy.get('span')
  .then($span => {
    return $span.text()                        // extract test
      .split(': ')                             // split it at ": "
  })
  .should('deep.equal', ['Book', 'English'])   // compare to ordered array
```

Answer (score 2):

You have bold `<b>` elements, will need to add `b` in the selector

```js
cy.get('span b')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('eq', 'BookEnglish')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.get('span').then(span => {
        const words = span.split(':');
        const firstword = words[0]
        const secondword = words[1]
        cy.log(firstword, secondword);
```

Try this. Here we are splitting the pair of words by ":" and storing them in array vairabled and calling that variables. Array [0] will have the text "Book" and array [1] will have the text "English"

Comment: It's almost correct, but you need to extract the text from the `<span>`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you could just see if the whole string matches with `contains` after or as part of get

```js
cy.get('span').contains('Book: English').should('exist')
// or
cy.get('span:contains("Book: English")').should('exist')
```